# How cin to string?

Tags: c++, string, char, cin

I have got: `string ipAddress;`

When I try to: `cin>>ipAddress;` I get

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  c:\users\r\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\chat\chat\chat.cpp 158 1   Chat
```

How to replace this instruction?

Headers:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Socket.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Include headers you use.

Comment: `#include <string>`?

Comment: In some implementations of the standard library, when you include iostream you get parts of string, but it's always a good idea to include string yourself. Even if not including string is working for you today, in the next release of your compiler (or if you switch compilers) it might not, so include what you need and you'll live a simpler life.

Answer (score 6):

Try including the function declaration for `std::string` by:
`#include <string>`

Answer (score -1):

use std::getline http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

```
string ipAddress
std::getline(cin, ipAddress);
```

Comment: This reads in an entire text line and not a "word".  It may not be exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.